# Find Range of Excel Array Formula

Tags: arrays, excel, named-ranges

A certain cell is part of a range containing an array formula (created using CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER). Other than my brute force method of visually examining the formula in the certain cell, does Excel have a command that will highlight the range of cells which contain the array formula? For instance, assume C10 has the following array formula ={TRANSPOSE(myarray)}, how can I ask Excel to highlight the range of cells that will receive the contents of the transposed "myarray"?

This feels like a Excel 101 question but my search has been futile.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no "junk" below the array formula, something like:

```
=COUNTA(C10:C9999)
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t clear. I want to be able to click on a cell that is part of an array formula and via some context sensitive native excel command, have all the cells that make up the array formula be selected.